# Conditions met a maximum of one time in the 25 previous bars

Tags: pine-script

I would like to check if prior to entry (long or short) if each of the following conditions are met a maximum of one time in the 25 previous bars :

```
bullishMACross = ta.crossover(close, thirdmaHigh)
bearishMACross = ta.crossunder(close, thirdmaLow)
```

I have tried to code it clumsily as followed :

```
var int trend_countbullishMACross = 0
if bullishMACross
    trend_countbullishMACross := trend_countbullishMACross + 1 // Increment the counter if condition is met

var int trend_countbearishMACross = 0
if bearishMACross
    trend_countbearishMACross := trend_countbearishMACross + 1 // Increment the counter if condition is met

trend_counterbullishMA = trend_countbullishMACross <= 1
trend_counterbearishMA = trend_countbearishMACross <= 1

entryAllowed = (trend_counterbullishMA == true) and (trend_counterbearishMA == true)

if (entryAllowed)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message = "US30 Long Entry Taken")
    trend_countbullishMACross:=0
    trend_countbearishMACross:=0
```

but it doesn't work.

Would appreciate some expertise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that will plot the most recent event on the chart. Adjust which sma you're using accordingly:

```
//@version=5
indicator("sma14", overlay=true)

length = 14
thirdmaHigh = ta.sma(close, length)
thirdmaLow = ta.sma(close, length)

bullishMACross = ta.crossover(close, thirdmaHigh)
bearishMACross = ta.crossunder(close, thirdmaLow)

var int lastCrossoverBar = na
var bool lastCrossoverIsBullish = na

// most recent crossover
for i = 0 to 24
    if bullishMACross[i]
        if na(lastCrossoverBar) or i < lastCrossoverBar
            lastCrossoverBar := bar_index[i]
            lastCrossoverIsBullish := true
    if bearishMACross[i]
        if na(lastCrossoverBar) or i < lastCrossoverBar
            lastCrossoverBar := bar_index[i]
            lastCrossoverIsBullish := false

plotCondition = bar_index == lastCrossoverBar
plotshape(series=plotCondition and lastCrossoverIsBullish, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small, title="Bullish MA Cross")
plotshape(series=plotCondition and not lastCrossoverIsBullish, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small, title="Bearish MA Cross")
```

[image]